# Is my answer to the question which uses Lagrange method to find $\min_{x_1,x_2,x_3 >0}\sum_{i=1}^3 \ln x_i$ correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

Question: Given a constant $m > 0$, use the Lagrange method to solve the problem:

$$\min_{x_1,x_2,x_3 >0}\sum_{i=1}^3 \ln x_i \text{ such that } \sum _{i=1}^3 x_i = m$$

My try:
$$L(x,\lambda) = \sum_{i=1}^3 \ln x_i + \lambda (\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i - m )= 0$$

$$\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}xi}L(x,\lambda)$$ = 1/x<sub>i</sub> +  = 0 =>  = -1/x<sub>i</sub>

x<sub>i</sub> = (-1/) for i = 1, 2, 3.
Hence 3(-1/) = m =>  = -3/m =>
-3/m  = -1/x<sub>i</sub> =>x<sub>i</sub> = m/3

x<sup>*</sup> = (m/3, m/3, m/3)

Is my answer correct?

Comment: These appear to be two different questions, so you should open a second post for the second question and remove that from this question.

Comment: Okay, I've made the necessary edit :)

Comment: Note that $\min\sum\log x_i$ is the same problem as $\min\prod x_i$.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to ask for the derivative relative to $x$, since $x$ is a sequence of 3 values.  You should take the derivative of $L$ in 4 ways: with respect to $x_1, x_2, x_3, \text{ and } \lambda$ .  That should give you the system of equations to solve and check.

Comment: I have edited my question and updated my answer. Is it correct?

Comment: @Quant007 Your calculation of $\lambda$ is correct, your calculation of $x_i$ following that is mistaken.  Also, all you find with the lagrange multiplier is an interior critical point, it could be a minimum or a maximum or neither.  You need to check boundary conditions.  Hint, what is $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \ln(x)$ ?

Comment: @Quant007 Your calculation for $x_i$ is still incorrect.  But just for a moment, forget about lagrange multipliers, what is the value of the min when $x_1 = e^{-3000}, x_2 = e^{-3000}, x_3 \approx m$ ?

Comment: x1 and x2 are very close to 0. I know that lim→0+ [ln()] = -∞. x3 is probably bigger than x1 and x2.

Answer (score 0):

Making $x_i = \mu_i^2$ and solving now the lagrangian

$$
L(\mu,\lambda) = \sum_i\ln(\mu_i^2)+\lambda\left(\sum_i\mu_i^2-m\right)
$$

here, essentially we have $x_i\ge 0$ and then the stationary points are the solutions for

$$
\cases{
\frac{2}{\mu_i}+2\lambda\mu_i=0,\ \ \ i=1,\cdots,n\\
\sum_i\mu_i^2-m=0
}
$$

and $\lambda=-\frac{1}{\mu_i^2}$ so $n(-\frac{1}{\lambda})-m=0$ hence $\lambda = -\frac nm$ or

$$
\frac{2}{\mu_i}+2\left(-\frac nm\right)\mu_i=0,\ \ \ i=1,\cdots,n
$$

thus obtaining

$$
\mu_i^2 = \frac mn = x_i\ge  0
$$

Comment: I believe you just found a maximum.

Comment: Yes. The stationary point is a maximum. The minimum is unbounded as any of the $x_i\to 0$

Comment: @DanielV could you please write the proper solution for the minimum as a separate answer here? :) I'll be sure to leave an upvote :)